# Upgrade-safe customizations of files in root of Suite CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Is there the way for upgrade-safe customization of files in the root folder of Suite CRM? I know how to customize files in "include" folder, for example (place them in the "custom/include"), but i cannot understand how i can change the file (i need to edit /download.php) in the root directory of the project in upgrade save manner.

Comment: You can only feasibly do upgrade safe customisation in the custom directory, not in the root. There are exceptions such as config_override.php, but I'm now aware of an upgrade safe way to customise download.php.

Comment: Crap. It's bad. I need to store all uploaded files on Amazon S3 instead of our server, and i need to modify download.php for this purpose.

Comment: It's possible for you to use version control to watch the file, and then just check for conflicts when you run an upgrade. It won't be "upgrade safe" but it should achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've came to the conclusion its not possible to integrate S3 buckets in a non upgrade safe manner, the following files need integrated with your S3 code.

- include/upload_file.php
- modules/Documents/Document.php
- modules/Emails/Email.php
- modules/InboundEmail/InboundEmail.php
- modules/Notes/Note.php

Comment: This would be interesting to offer as a Sugar/SuiteCRM module. I think it's a major deficit of the architecture to store email attachments along side application code :)